# Cucumber-jvm runner with many features, just run one

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have this project structure:

```
/src
   /it
      /java
         /com/xxx/test/it
            ContextSteps
            /inventory
               InventoryIT
               InventorySteps                                          
      /resources
         /com/xxx/test/it/inventory  
            1.feature
            2.feature
```

Runner `InventoryIT` (both features are annotated with `@inventory`)

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = "@inventory")
public class InventoryIT {
}
```

*Note that `ContextSteps` in injected in `InventorySteps` through `cucumber-picocontainer`.*

When I execute project tests through this runner (with maven or from the IDE as well), I expect both `1.feature` and `2.feature` run (because both are placed in the same resources package), but just runs the first one: `1.feature`.

Am I missing something?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still wondering why is just running one of the two features... can be fixed setting manually the features resources path:

`features = "src/it/resources/com/xxx/test/it/inventory"`)

through `@CucumberOptions` annotation in the `InventoryIT` runner.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = "@inventory", features = "src/it/resources/com/xxx/test/it/inventory")
public class InventoryIT {
}
```

Making this change, both feature run.